# Show data from row to jquery popup dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to show value in textbox of popup form.

```
function eopen(id) {    
    edialog.dialog("open");
    item_id = id;
    //show id in span field.
    $('#item-id').text(item_id);
    //how to show related columns for a id in text box below..
    $('#editname').val(??????);
```

And this is data content loaded from database...

```
echo '<div><span class="item-name">'. $item[$i]['gitem_name'] . '</span>';
echo '<a class="edit-name" id="'. $item[$i]['gitem_id'] .'">edit</a>';
```

This is my click function for value edit..

```
$('.edit-name').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    eopen($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

And this is popup form values..

```
<span>Global ID : </span><span id="item-id" class="dialog-text"></span>
<input type="text" id="editname" style="width: 100%;" name="editname">
```

Comment: Can you show the generated `html` of your content load from database?

Comment: i have declare edialog on first line so its working...

Comment: how to show that please send the code...

Comment: _how to show related columns for a id in text box below.._ what does this mean as in the comment.

Comment: oh sorry may be i am wrong..

Comment: my database like -> ID | Name - i need to show the name for the ID in text box .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** and **[`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)**

```
function eopen(id) {    
   edialog.dialog("open");
   item_id = id;
   //show id in span field.
   $('#item-id').text(item_id);
   var value=$("#"+id).closest('div').find('.item-name').text();
   //get its parent with .closest and find item-name in it and get its text
   $('#editname').val(value);
}
```

Comment: this working but one small problem  adding (value +  value)  on close popup and select next